# Alternate row color for List View - uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How can I set alternate row color for listview? I'am setting each item as datatemplate.Binding values to textblock. So can't Iterate through listview item.How can I achieve it?

```
 <ListView x:Name="list1"  Width="300" Height="500" Background="White"  Loaded="list1_Loaded"   Style="{StaticResource FixedHeaderListViewStyle}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid Tapped="StackPanel_Tapped" Width="300" Height="38">                    
                    <Border  Width="390" Height="38"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ItemUserName}" Padding="4" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

  private void list1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        ItemCollection ic = listView.Items;
        int counter = 1;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in ic)
        {
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
            {
                item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
            }
            else
            {
                item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.OrangeRed);
                item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Snow);
            }
            counter++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: does your list have `OrangeRed` and `Snow` colors? or does not contain any colors at all? try and debug the counter to see if its working properly.

Comment: control is not going to  foreach (ListViewItem item in ic) loop

Comment: well change the question to foreach is not working then.. are you sure ic has any data? are you getting an exception or it just does not enter the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution as below

```
void BackgroundAlternatingListView_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ItemIndex % 2 != 0)
    {
        args.ItemContainer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_secondColor);
    }
    else
    {
        args.ItemContainer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_startColor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `<AlternatingItemTemplate>` and set a different color for it, no code on the controller is needed.

Comment: `AlternatingItemTemplate` is not supported in UWP